# NoSQL embedded database with data change notification callback

Tags: .net, sqlite, nosql, embedded-database, litedb

I am using SQLite embedded in a .Net Desktop application developed with WPF.
SQLite provides a callback for any write operation performed to the database (within the same connection) [ref](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/update_hook.html)

In this callback, it provides the following which leads to the records being affected

- Event (Insert /Update/Delete)
- Table Name
- Row Id

I am looking for a **NoSQL alternative** that also provides such callback and could be embedded in a desktop application targeting **.Net Framework 4.8**

I like the lightweight [LiteDB](https://www.litedb.org/) but couldn't find data changes callback support

Comment: MongoDB please check this article 
https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.9/reference/driver/change_streams/

Comment: Thanks, @MohemanTariq, It is a client application, distributing MongoDB with the app will be a huge dependency. I was looking for a lightweight solution like LiteDB, which could maintain data in just a single file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the [Realm](https://realm.io/) Database.
Realm lets [register a notification handler on a specific collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/dotnet/examples/react-to-changes/#register-a-collection-change-listener). The handler receives a description of changes since the last notification. Specifically, this description consists of three lists of indices:

- The indices of the objects that were deleted.
- The indices of the objects that were inserted.
- The indices of the objects that were modified.

Another plus point of Realm over SQLite is that these change notifications are NOT limited to changes from the same connection.